# Loop within a single cell

Tags: vba, loops

Hi am very new to VBA and am struggling quite a bit. Basically I am trying to use excel to increase the number of wind turbines and solar panels in a loop until the budget has been reached

```
Dim Turbines As Integer, SolarPanels As Integer

If Range("Total_Budget") < 50000 Then

    For Turbines = 1 To 10
        For SolarPanels = 0 To 1000 Step 50

            Range("TNumber") = Turbines
            Range("SPower") = SolarPanels
        Exit For

    Next Turbines

Next SolarPanels

End If

End Sub
```

The `TNumber` and `SPower` and single cell named ranges. When I try to run the code I get an error:-

> Invalid next control variable reference.

Like I said I am new to VBA and  struggling to get my head around it so apologies if my problem doesn't make complete sense

Comment: *"increase the number of ... in a loop until the budget has been reached"* sounds like you are trying hard to avoid plain old division here.

Comment: You are missing `Next SolarPanels`?

Comment: Next turbines should be after next solarPanels....

Comment: Swap the lines

Next Turbines
Next SolarPanels

Comment: Are you wanting to check how many of each combined and one at a time, or check how many Turbines to reach the budget, and how many Solar Panels to reach the budget (i.e separately) Also I see no reference to the actual budget if this could change. Does the query need to include he amount in the Total_Budget range and decrease it until it's 0?

Comment: Thanks SteFanR looks like that was a very simple error to fix. Tomalak all the formulas and calculations have been done in the excel spreadsheets so its just the variables that I needed to change. Trying to do optimisation but right now it is a very slow process

Comment: Ideally as the turbine is more expensive I would like the use turbines and then top up the remaining with solar panels. Ie. If the budget is £100000 and each turbine costs £30000 and each solar panel costs £10000 the results would give me TNumber=3 and SolarPanels=1

Comment: Your `For SolarPanels...` loop will execute exactly once. It will set the two `Range("...")`, then it will hit `Exit For` and exit the `SolarPanels` loop and pass on to `Next Turbines`. Unless that's what you really want, remove that line. Also, based on the way this code is written (with the two `Next` lines swapped. Your loops will run until `Turbines=10` and `SolarPanels=1000`. Every. Single. Time. There is no checking within your loop to see if your current expenditure has exceeded your total budget.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236768/loop-within-a-single-cell#comment77440047_45236768), this could all be done with formulas:

Set your TurbineCount cell:
`=INT(Total_Budget/CostPerTurbine)`

Set your SolarPanel count cell:
`=INT((Total_Budget-(TurbineCount*CostPerTurbine))/CostPerSolarPanel)`

and be done with it.

`INT()` rounds down to the nearest whole number so you won't end up with a partial turbine or panel.

---

If you *have* to do it in VBA:

```
Public Sub CalcTurbinesAndPanels()

  Dim TotalBudget as Range
  Set TotalBudget = ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.Range("Total_Budget")
  If  TotalBudget.Value < 50000 Then
    Dim TurbineCount as Range
    Set TurbineCount = ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.Range("TNumber")

    Dim TurbineCost as Range
    Set TurbineCost = ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.Range("TurbineCost")

    TurbineCount.Value = TotalBudget.Value / TurbineCost.Value

    Dim RemainingBudget as Long
    RemainingBudget = TotalBudget.Value - (TurbineCount.Value * TurbineCost.Value)

    Dim PanelCount as Range
    Set PanelCount = ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.Range("SPower")

    Dim PanelCost as Range
    Set PanelCost = ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.Range("SolarPanelCost")
    PanelCount.Value = RemainingBudget / PanelCost.Value

  End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

- I'm making the assumption that there are some additional named ranges for your *TurbineCount*, *SolarPanelCount*, *TurbineCost* and *SolarPanelCost* cells. Adjust as necessary.
- Declaring `Range` variables and setting them equal to the range they refer to means less typing in the long run on longer functions.

  - I added `ThisWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.` to at least force the references to always point to the Workbook/Worksheet in which the code is running.
  - This is probably an insignificant point in such a small routine, but it's a good idea to start proper habits early.
- `.Value` is the default property of a `Range` so you don't need to use it, but I'm putting it in to make it more explicit
- `Range()` always refers to the current, `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveWorksheet`. Using an unqualified `Range()` in your code is asking for trouble in the long run - at some point, you, your user or your code will switch to a different worksheet and everything will break with weird errors that are difficult to track down and could potentially cause significant damage to the data in your workbook.
- Doing this in code is *significant* overkill unless the format of the worksheet is locked down and you are not able/allowed to add or edit formulas.
- This was some quick code off the top of my head. It hasn't been tested or even written in the VBE. Some minor typos may exist. YMMV.